# Can't create auto-click in HTML embed player

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, eventtrigger, autoplay

So I am building a web site with goDaddy. I am using the embed player below to shoutcast my music on the page.

```html
<script>(function (win, doc, script, source, objectName) { (win.RadionomyPlayerObject = win.RadionomyPlayerObject || []).push(objectName); win[objectName] = win[objectName] || function (k, v) { (win[objectName].parameters = win[objectName].parameters || { src: source, version: '1.1' })[k] = v; }; var js, rjs = doc.getElementsByTagName(script)[0]; js = doc.createElement(script); js.async = 1; js.src = source; rjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, rjs); }(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.radionomy.com/js/radionomy.player.js', 'radplayer'));
radplayer('url', '-oktm');
radplayer('type', 'horizontal');
radplayer('autoplay', '0');
radplayer('volume', '50');
radplayer('color1', '#000000');
radplayer('color2', '#ffffff');
</script>
<div class="radionomy-player"></div>
```

My problem is the autoplay function. If I enable it, it won't autoplay on Android (Chrome) and iOS. I have read why this happens so I thought another way to autoplay. I want to trigger the play button after the page and plugin have loaded. I tried to do it with some simple JQuery or Java but I had no success. If someone could modify the code for me so it will load paused and then after 1 second it triggers the play button, it will be highly appreciated.
Thanks is advance.

Comment: Please show your attempts to do this in JQuery or JavaScript so we have something to work with.

Comment: I tried the click method with jquery
` $(document).ready(function(){
  $('svgPlay').trigger('click');
}); `
And I tried to change the svgPlay to other variants but I had no result.

Answer (score 1):

Android, iOs mobile browsers don't support autoplay, they require human interaction - touch a screen or click a button, they will not play anything without that. That is for user bandwidth protection.

Comment: I know about that, I also mentioned it in my question above. What I want to do is make the Play button of the player auto-click after the page is loaded. Not the autoplay funtion. Just an auto-click on the Play button of the player.

Comment: Auto-clicking on that button will not help.

Answer (score 0):

Android and iOS have disabled this with purpose. Imagine browsing the web with your phone and all the video advertisements that could be playing in the background will just simply eat up all your bandwith.

While working with hybrid HTML clients, I used this trick/workaround to start autoplaying videos: 
When user entered the page for the first time, then `<video>` element with empty src has to be created the page(hidden somewhere). Whenever user touches the screen for the first time for whatever reason, then I tried to invoke play method on the video element(this breaks the first usergesture on html video element). This will usually give a small error/warning in console but that is okay because what matters is that the first user gesture has been made, thus enabling you to use `play()` method whenever you want! So after the first user gesture has been made, you simply just have to use the same `<video>` element!

I hope this helps.

Comment: Nice workaround man! I am going to try that as well but first I want to try and make the Play button of the audio player auto-click after the page is loaded. Just like the user presses it. It is not the autplay function that the mobile browsers have disabled. It's more like an automated click.

Comment: @SavvasMohito I hope this helps, let me know how it works out for you :)